# CSS. Задать стиль для ссылки для телефона

Tags: html, css, шрифты, href

Можете подсказать, как поменять стиль у ссылки для телефона в CSS?
Меняю стиль, а изменяется только шрифт. Т.е в браузере телефон отображается, как ссылка. Мне же нужно отобразить телефон, как текст, но при этом сделать его "кликабельным".
[image: Фото телефона и ссылки]
Сам код:

```css
.telephonereplymidle {
    color: black;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "OpenSans";
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0.208;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 22.58px;
    top: 129.009px;
    width: 414px;
    height: 42px;
    border-bottom-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="telephonereplymidle"><a  href="tel:+78422993366">8 (8422) 99 - 33 - 66</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще в `<div>` нет необходимости... Можно объединить в один `a` тэг с классом.

Ну если Вам надо убрать синее подчеркивание, то используйте `text-decoration: none`.

```css
.telephonereplymidle {
    color: black;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "OpenSans";
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0.208;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 22.58px;
    top: 129.009px;
    width: 414px;
    height: 42px;
    border-bottom-style: dashed;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a  href="tel:+78422993366" class="telephonereplymidle">8 (8422) 99 - 33 - 66</a>
```